# How do we pass objects of generic class to a method in Java

Tags: java, class, object, generics, inheritance

I have two class as follows-

```
public class Test1 {
  private int a;
  private int b;
  public setA(int a) {this.a=a;}
  public setB(int b) {this.b=b;}
}

public class Test2 extends Test1 {
  private int c;
  public setC(int c) {this.c=c;}
}
```

I am looking for a method to call which will set the values of a and b, if i pass an object of either Test1 or Test2

```
public class Test3 {
  Test1 obj1 = new Test1();
  Test2 obj2 = new Test2();

  public static void main() {
    populateAB(obj1);
    populateAB(obj2);
  }
  
  public void populateAB(???something obj) {
    obj.setA(5);
    obj.setB(10);
  }
}
```

What should be the prototype of populateAB() to accept objects from both Test1 and Test2 and call the setter functions?

Comment: I suggest you research inheritance on the internet. Loads of examples like this to be found. Perhaps this explains your question a bit? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182141/java-inheritance-example

Comment: You need to make use of constructors to achieve what you are expecting in a more cleaner way

Comment: Your question is rather about the `Inheritance` rather than `Generics` of Java. Commonly speaking, any sub-type instance can be assigned to their parent type variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `???something` to `Test1` you will be able to call `obj.setA()` and `obj.setB()`. As you are using inheritance you will be able to call `populateAB` with and object of class `Test1` and with an object of class `Test2`.
But you won't be able to use the setter or getter of the property `c` of class `Test2`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Test2` inherits from `Test1` you can simply use `Test1` as the datatype.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 obj1 = new Test1();
        Test2 obj2 = new Test2();

        populateAB(obj1);
        populateAB(obj2);

        System.out.println(obj1);
        System.out.println(obj2);
    }

    public static void populateAB(Test1 obj) {
        obj.setA(5);
        obj.setB(10);
    }
}

class Test1 {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    public void setA(int a) {this.a=a;}
    public void setB(int b) {this.b=b;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format( "[a = %d; b = %d ]", a, b );
    }
}

class Test2 extends Test1 {
    private int c;
    public void setC(int c) {this.c=c;}
}
```

Output:

```
[a = 5; b = 10 ]
[a = 5; b = 10 ]
```

Its the same with the `toString()` Method which is part of the `Object` class but every Object inherits from the `Object` class so they have access to those methods and also can be stored all together in an `Object[]` or something

Another example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Dog dog = new Dog( "Bello" );
        Cat cat = new Cat( "Garfield" );

        Animal[] animals = new Animal[] { dog, cat };

        for ( Animal animal : animals ) {
            System.out.println( animal.name );
        }
    }
}

class Animal {
    public String name;

    Animal( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {

    Cat( String name ) {
        super( name );
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {

    Dog( String name ) {
        super( name );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bello
Garfield
```

As you can see Im storing two different objects together as `Animals` since they both inherit from the `Animal` class.